# Use joinattribute in observer make search action error "Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in"

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

This is the observer to add custom column to customer grid, here is the code

```
public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getCollection();
    if (!isset($collection)) {
        return;
    }

    /*
    * Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection
    */
    if ($collection instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection) {
        /* @var $collection Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('billing_company');
        $collection->joinAttribute('billing_company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left'); 
    }
}
```

in config.xml

```
<eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
    <observers>
        <test_customer_collection_update>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>Test_Admin_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>beforeCollectionLoad</method>
        </test_customer_collection_update>
    </observers>
</eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
```

when i search the customer grid in company column , it return an error `"Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in D:\xampp\htdocs\m1\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php"`

anyone know how to fix it?